# How to achieve this context using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html

Trying to achieve this HTML shape where I'd like to place many photos inside this shape with `onclick` method there

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) `EventListener` rather than `onclick`.

eg.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('pictureButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('togglepic').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#togglepic {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="pictureButton">Click me</button><br/>
<img id="togglepic" src="https://imgur.com/VYWEWRF.png"/>
```

Obviously, instead of the `<img>` element, you could add your "carousel" element, but the principle is the same - simply change the `display:` property from `none` to `block`

Comment: Thank you...and can you tell me how to achieve such shape using HTML?

Comment: @Ramona I just told you it's better to use the `EventListener` than html's `onclick` :( If you really insist on having only one .html file, add this to the bottom of your `<body>` -  `<script>...js code from my answer...</script>`

Comment: Ok :) but  I mean how to draw such shape (pointed with arrow 'HTML shape') and how to fit these pictures in this shape using code.

Comment: Just search online for an image carousel / gallery. Theres loads of them on the internet, including stackoverflow

Comment: @Ramona one more thing, if this solved your question, please use the check-mark sign (✓) to mark the question as solved, so it can be 'archived' :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay. I accepted your answer as useful. Can you please upvote my post? It got -3 for no reason. Thank you.